# How to implement SIR model for node ranking in graph?

Tags: python, graph-theory

I am working on node ranking in complex networks. I have heard about the SIR (susceptible-infected-recovered) model in graphs that measures the infection power of each node as its spreader and influence rank (a node with high infected nodes has higher spreader rank). I saw several SIR source codes and even a library called ndlib in python for SIR model, but these implementations do not rank the nodes based on their infection power and just simulate the SIR.

How can I sort nodes of a graph based on the power of node in infecting other nodes?

Comment: Why can't you calculate the power of each node in infecting other nodes, put the result in a list or dictionary or other suitable data structure, and use the built-in `sorted` function?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the problem is that the source codes i found do not provide infected nodes for a node and do not rank. Do you have any source code or reference for SIR to learn it in details?

Comment: No, I have no such source code or reference.